# How to keep value "&" in Short text as it is?

Tags: sitefinity

In Sitefinity, I have a situation where I set `&` as value in Short text field. Then the value gets changed to `&amp;`. I need to keep the value as `&` in Short text box type.

[image]

Comment: What Sitefinity version is this? I can't reproduce the issue. Do you set the value in the SF backend or via the API?

Comment: I am using Sitefinity version 10.1.6502.0 and setting the values from backend. But my client wants values in plain text on sitefinity backend.

Comment: There must be something custom there, normally this works just fine for text fields.

Comment: This is happening for all the built in and custom modules and fields

Comment: The only thing I could suggest is - try this on a brand new project of the same version or upgrade to a later version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug in Sitefinity 10.1, please see [this](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/encoded-characters-are-displayed-escaped-in-the-backend-and-mvc-widgets?q=ampersand&l=en_US&c=Product_Group%3ASitefinity&fs=Search&pn=1) article for a workaround

In short, you should:

> Go to Administration >> Settings >> Advanced >> Data >> Data Processors >> XSS sanitizer and uncheck the "Enabled" checkbox.
>   Keep in mind, that by this the sanitizing of the input is stopped. Also, the previously created items with an ampersand, will not automatically change to '&', and this should be done manually.